# jython wsadmin script change to dmgr jvm

Tags: websphere, jython, wsadmin

I have a script that sets a Custom JVM Property at each of the node agents, but I also want it to do the same at the dmgr level.  I'm having a hard time getting the id for the dmgr jvm.  Here's my nodeagent script.  I'm really struggling with the list, listServers, getid differences.

Thanks to covener's comment, here's the working script

## List deplyment manager server

dmgrServer = AdminTask.listServers('[-serverType DEPLOYMENT_MANAGER]').splitlines()

for jvm in dmgrServer:
    # get dmgr jvm id
    jvmid = AdminConfig.list('JavaVirtualMachine', jvm)
    # create new property
    AdminConfig.create('Property', jvmid, '[[validationExpression ""] [name "MyProperty"] [description "Do cool stuff"] [value "true"] [required "false"]]')

## Get all the node agent servers

nodeagents = AdminTask.listServers('[-serverType NODE_AGENT]').splitlines()

for nodeagent in nodeagents:
    # get the id of the JVM for this node agent server
    jvmid = AdminConfig.list('JavaVirtualMachine', nodeagent)
    # set the custom property
    AdminConfig.create('Property', jvmid, '[[validationExpression ""] [name "MyProperty"] [description "Do cool stuff"] [value "true"] [required "false"]]')

## save the configuration changes

AdminConfig.save()

## sync all active nodes

AdminNodeManagement.syncActiveNodes()

Comment: Does the AdminTask.listServers('[-serverType DEPLOYMENT_MANAGER]') not work on your cell? It worked for me.

Comment: Thank you.  I couldn't find the list of serverType objects.  This was exactly what I wanted.  Now my script creates a property on the dmgr and nodeagent jvms in a consistent and easy to read way.

Answer (score 2):

Adding comment as an answer:

DEPLOYMENT_MANAGER is a valid server type, so it can be handled exactly the same as the NODE_AGENT loop:

```
dmgrServer = AdminTask.listServers('[-serverType DEPLOYMENT_MANAGER]').splitlines()
```